# I want to apply textures to face using the augmented faces example in arcore for unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

At Google I/O'19 for Augmenting Faces and Images, they said about reference_face_texture.PNG for painting or apply texture to specific areas in a face for example lips, cheeks etc. but i am unable to find this reference face texture, so that i can use it in Photoshop to apply textures to exact area i want to apply, and then apply the new created texture using the face tracker in augmented-faces arcore. Can somebody please highlight it. Thank you.

i did tried downloading facial mesh images from online, but it is not perfect match after applying the textures to mesh image.

Answer (score -1):

I could not find reference_face_texture as well, but you can open a reference 3D [model](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/assets/canonical_face_mesh.fbx) and make a UV texture. To save you time: [here is the texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1gyy.png)

Comment: Thanks alot for answer, helped alot